# jQuery Ajax Post() geting responce with zero.. why?

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery

I am working with word press . to submit a form with Ajax i use this code .. my php code is working fine and also j Query.

But when i am getting responce from `post()` and printing it.. 
it is printing with 'zero' means '0'..
As **"Mail send 0"**

**PHP Code**

```
 /* Apply Online form enqueue/localize/add action/function script start*/

    wp_register_script("ajax-apply_online", get_bloginfo('template_directory')."/js/custom_js.js", array( "jquery"));
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-apply_online');
    wp_localize_script("ajax-apply_online","the_ajax_apply_online", array("ajaxurl_apply_online" => admin_url("admin-ajax.php")));

// add actions
   add_action( "wp_ajax_apply_online", "ajax_action_apply_online" );
   add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_apply_online", "ajax_action_apply_online" );

   function ajax_action_apply_online(){
     echo "Mail Send";                  
  }
/* Apply Online  form enqueue/localize/add action/function script end*/
```

**jQuery Code**

```
 jQuery.post(the_ajax_apply_online.ajaxurl_apply_online,
                    jQuery("#apply_online_form").serialize(),
                        function(response_from_the_action_function){

                            jQuery("#errfrmMsg").val(response_from_the_action_function).css({"display":"block"});
                        }
            );
```

Comment: try adding `exit;` after `echo "Mail Send"; `. Also inspect response in browser console to see what is actually being sent

Comment: @charlietfl i solved with your comment.. please change it in post ans.. i will tick as ans..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding exit; after echo "Mail Send";

If some other part of the php that executes after the `mail send` is adding additional text this will stop it from running